# Registering an iphone app, bundle id registered as domain name

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I'm new to ios development and when reserving my app name on the apple app store, the bundle id ended up being registered as a domain name like **mysite.com**  I've since read it should be using a reserved domain name like com.mysite.myappname; will my current configuration cause problems down the road and is there anything I can do to fix it if there is?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to IOS development, I do reckon its not too late to recreate your Bundle Id.

I did faced some issue a few years back with the Bundle ID not in the correct format when upon uploading Itunes Connect rejecting the binary.

But i can't advise if that is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to add a new bundle id.  Now, since I wanted to make my app name the same as my domain (ie. My Site), my bundle id ended up being com.mysite.mysite  Is this ok, or is there some other convention I should follow for naming the appname?

Comment: That is perfectly fine.  Apple's guidance on this topic is reverse DNS style just as you have it.  The key aspect of Bundle IDs is that they are unique across the iOS ecosystem.  How do you know if yours is unique? If the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool allows you to create the AppId without error, then you are good to go.